# saving a text file to edge node from spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to save a text file to edge node from spark.

to test my code i am reading a sample file from hdfs as dataset and writing it to edge node..please find my code below

```
val dataone = sparkSession.read.textFile("/user/projects/folder1/employee.txt")
 dataone.write.mode("append").format("text").save("file:///edge_node_folder1/edge_node_folder2/employee.txt")
```

in HDFS my sample file is in the text file format. But on edge node its getting saved as part files inside a folder naming employee.txt

is there a way to save file as text file on edge node(not inside a folder) and with the same name as mentioned in path(and not the auto-generated names as hadoop gives to its part files in my case on edge node the text file is getting saved inside employee.txt folder as

```
part-00000-808ccd9e-7b7d-4b63-88ae-782d40bb272f-c000.txt
_SUCCESS
```

)

Answer (score 0):

With "toLocalIterator" single file can be created manually:

```
val fos = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/edge_node_folder1/edge_node_folder2/employee.txt"))
val it = dataone.toLocalIterator()
while (it.hasNext) {
  fos.write(it.next())
  fos.write(System.lineSeparator())
}
fos.close()
```

Comment: i am not sure what u are trying to do can u please elaborate step wise. while i am running the first line val fos = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/edge_node_folder1/edge_node_folder2/employee.txt")) it is showing that employee.txt is a directory which is true

Comment: Provided code can be used  instead of " dataone.write.mode("append")". Existed directory "employee.txt" can be renamed (or deleted if not required) before run.

Comment: Also other script can be used after "dataone.write.mode("append")": directory "employee.txt" scanned by trivial code, and all files included in new result file.